# Moving a TYPO3 site to a server without Composer

Tags: composer-php, typo3, typo3-10.x

I built a TYPO3 site locally (10.4.9), where TYPO3 was set up using Composer.

After moving the site to our TYPO webserver, which does not use Composer but Syslinks (which I configured), the front-end only returns an Oops-error page. The backend, however, works.

For some odd reason I could get none of the settings that would give me a more detailed error message to work.

I suspect the issue is with the lack of Composer on the server.

For example, these lines in the index.php file:

```
call_user_func(function () {
    $classLoader = require dirname(__DIR__).'/vendor/autoload.php';
    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Core\SystemEnvironmentBuilder::run(0, \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Core\SystemEnvironmentBuilder::REQUESTTYPE_FE);
    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Core\Bootstrap::init($classLoader)->get(\TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Http\Application::class)->run();
});
```

What can be done in this case?

If I install Composer on the server, will it affect the other TYPO3-sites on it?

Or is there an alternative fix for it?

Comment: Please share more details, like an exact error message. There is no need to install Composer on any remote server, just use your usual deployment process to include all needed libraries

Comment: Hi! Knowning your backend works is already a sign that you properly deployed your website, so composer probably is not the issue. Could you turn on displayErrors in your `LocalConfiguration.php` so that you can see what the real issue is? I highly suspect that you configured your website for your previous domain but not the domain you try to access it on the new server.

Comment: I turned on `displayErrors` and also set `debug` to `true` in `LocalConfiguration.php`. Still, all I get is "Oops, an error occurred!"

The domain should be configured, both on the server and in TYPO3

Answer (score 0):

Until now you can install and run TYPO3 without composer. although there are some differences in handling.

As there is no composer which fetches all extensions you need to do it in another way. You have two options:

1. import extensions in the extension manager from TER
2. copy extensions to /typo3conf/ext/... yourself

Drawback:

- not all extensions are available in TER (with all versions)
- extensions which need additional libraries may be incomplete or you must provide these external code into your installation

Another difference: instead of the composer autoloader you need another autoloader (and your extension must support it). Otherwise some classes are missing.

What your installation is missing needs more information. Aside from the errorlog you could configure your system to give it in the browser:

Switch your installation to debug-mode in the install-tool/admin-tool to get an error-dump in the frontend.

---

You can have different TYPO3 installations (composer based / non composer based) side by side on a server. So it is possible to install composer and use it for one single installation only without changing all other installations.

Answer (score 0):

My answer refers to a special kind of transfer to the server:

> In a perhaps old document it was advised to do the composer-installation and copy that to the server - per FTP (preferable as archive to transfer only one large file).
> On the server itself composer wasn't expected to be available.

This scenario has some caveats because TYPO3 is using composer even after installation (i.e. rebuilding the autoload files).

Nevertheless it might work if the caveats are always taken into consideration.
The problem to consider is that it isn't sufficient to copy the web-folder with the common  files and subfolders on the server but it's also required to copy the `vendor`-folder, that usually is outside of the web-directory of TYPO3. Also it's probably desired to map the domain on the folder `public`, the folders `vendor` and public are parallel in the same main-directory.
Here is an installation where the folder `public` is only one of several that are required to use TYPO3:

[image]

The name of the parent folder is in my case `v10c` but can be anything else, usually the name of the project or customer.
Other structures are possible, depending on the composer-setup but the problem is always the same:
**the structure of the local installation has to be copied completely on the server, it's not enough to copy only the folder `public`.**

Beside that it has to be considered that paths in autoload-files are perhaps not applying to the server and had to be adjusted.

**I wouldn't recommended using TYPO3 like this and it's possible that there exist further problems I didn't consider.** But in general it's probably possible to get it like this running.